# Checking if a Javascript object contains the same key/value Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

Can't figure out how to find an equal key:value in the array consisted of objects.

I have an Array with the objects that look like this

```
[{
0:false, 
1:false, 
2:false, 
3:true, 
4:false, 
5:false
},{
0:false, 
1:false, 
2:false, 
3:true, 
4:false, 
5:false
},{
0:false, 
1:false, 
2:false, 
3:true, 
4:false, 
5:false
}]
```

I need to iterate this Array with objects and if all Objects get the same key with true value (In the example above all objects have the same `key:3` with `value: true`) and then I need to catch this key (position).

What is the best solution for this? I also use Lodash so maybe with this library it easy to get what I want or maybe to use plain javascript. It's no matter how to get it, just need a right solution.

Comment: I agree with you that it may be not a difficult job. But I've tried to search on StackOverflow the answer or solution and had not a success because here in Objects there are different keys that why I decided to ask.

Comment: Fair enough. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`_.findKey`](https://lodash.com/docs#findKey) and [`_.every`](https://lodash.com/docs#every)

```js
var arr = [{"0":false,"1":false,"2":false,"3":true,"4":false,"5":false},{"0":false,"1":false,"2":false,"3":true,"4":false,"5":false},{"0":false,"1":false,"2":false,"3":true,"4":false,"5":false}];

var key = _.findKey(arr[0], function(val, key) {
  return val && _.every(arr, key);
});
                        
console.log(key);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you're using ES6, you can shorten that to:

```
let key = _.findKey(arr[0], (v, k) => v && _.every(arr, k));
```

If you decide to switch to a more natural 2D array structure, use [`_.findIndex`](https://lodash.com/docs#findIndex) instead.

```
[
  [false,false,false,true,false,false],
  [false,false,false,true,false,false],
  [false,false,false,true,false,false],
  [false,false,false,true,false,false],
  [false,false,false,true,false,false]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I changed the objects with the keys being the index to arrays for simplicity, because that's what an array is: just [a special object with indices as keys](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp).

---

You can try this. It doesn't use lodash (I'm not familiar with it, sorry), but what it does is:

1. Start with an array of all `true` values that matches the length of each object (i.e., length is six)
2. Loop through each object and each property of each object.
3. If it is `false`, then the value of that index is `false`. If it is true, then the index will be `true` if the index is already `true`.
4. Print out the index that remains `true`.

You can see what I mean with the code below:

```js
var list = [[false,false,false,true,false,false],[false,false,false,true,false,false],[false,false,false,true,false,false],[false,false,false,true,false,false],[false,false,false,true,false,false]];

var trueKeys = [true, true, true, true, true, true];
for(obj in list)
  for(prop in list[obj])
    trueKeys[prop] = trueKeys[prop] && list[obj][prop];
var index = trueKeys.indexOf(true);

console.log(index);
```

Comment: There's no need to iterate over all of the values in every array. Just find the index of `true` in the first array, and then check that all of the rest of the arrays also have `true` at that index. This is making an O(n+m) operation into O(n*m)

Comment: I didn't realize that, @4castle. Thanks